# sync table from a csv?

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.2

I have a CSV which I'd like to sync with an existing table. The table should update with the values from the CSV or insert new rows if a key isn't found.  Is this possible? I can't seem to find anything on it, other than simply importing the csv. Only thing I can think of is writing a script in another language to go line by line of the csv, and check each row that way. Is there a way to achieve this with just a single sql script?

Comment: Time to update: 10.2 already reached EOL. Maybe you also want to share information about csv file: is it stored on client or on server?

Comment: We'll be upgrading once we move over to rhel9, still on cent7. It's not a customer-facing server. The csv is generated by my powershell script to dump AD users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `LOAD DATA INFILE` on a table with a Unique index or Primary key, new records will be inserted.

Duplicates can be handled in one of three ways:

- Using the `REPLACE` keyword, will replace the entire row with the
  incoming data
- Using the `IGNORE` keyword will discard the incoming
  row.
- With neither keyword, a duplicate will throw an error and the
  `LOAD` will stop.

If you want more control over how to handle duplicates (updating just one column in an existing row, for example) you'll need to write something to read the CSV file and insert the rows, one by one.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-error-handling

Comment: Does the CSV have to match the same number of columns? I think I'd be ok using REPLACE except for a single column that I've excluded from my csv.

Comment: No. You can map the CSV fields to the columns exactly as you would anyway. the `REPLACE` option will create new rows for any duplicates it finds, using the default value for the column from the table definition, or whatever value you've specifically entered for it in your map. You can find all the details for this on the page I've linked.

Comment: I've got it worked out, thanks.